# Entity framework with linq in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using *linq* query to group by element through one table field, `guid`.

The problem is that I do not know how to retrieve the object on the view.

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult Index2()
{
    List<Imageupload> lists = db.Imageuploads.ToList();
    var a = lists.GroupBy(g => g.guid);

    return View(a);
}
```

*Imageupload* is a modal class and *Imageuploads* is a table in the database.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var groupedList = db.Imageuploads
    .GroupBy(u => u.guid)
    .Select(g=> g.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Hope this helps